# Is there anyway to obfuscate a public JavaScript file in angular(not external libraries)?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, minify, uglifyjs

I have an angular project in which, I need to keep a file publicly accessible and it should get obfuscated at the time of production build.

I have tried the third-party libraries to do the job, but I need to run a separate npm script to do it, is there any way that angular(web-pack) can take care?

```
"build:prod": "yarn curl:prod && node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --c=production",
```

Prod build did not help.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean obfuscate? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)

Comment: @DaveIdito, Yes. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Extend your package.json with a "prod" script:

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --sourceMap false",
    ...
  },
```

And then just run it:
`npm run build:prod`

Comment: It did obfuscate the file